# Google Analytics: how to track search queries from search engine?

Tags: google-analytics, search-engines, keywords

I can't find search queries report in Analytics, besides the one under the column AdWords. There used to be one, as this screenshot shows:

[image]

I once read that Google Analytics no longer provide search terms report, because of privacy reasons--[though Google seem to still collect this data](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/what-analytics-is-hiding/). Is there still a way to get to know what keywords visitors used to get into our website?

Answer (score 2):

The report has recently been renamed: now you'll find the data under **Acquisition > Search console > Queries**. For this, you need to connect the Search Console with Google Analytics. In addition, this data is only for Google, not for Bing or other search engines like Yandex or Baidu.

[image]

Comment: I have connected that a few months ago. But there's no data in both my Analytics and Search Console. I have set the preferred domain to http://domain.com but still none.

Comment: If there is no data in the Search Console, something is certainly wrong with the setup. Did you verify the ownership of the domain? Does the domain name match with the domain name in use? Did you specify https/http correctly?

Comment: Search console usually takes a few weeks to get data.   Is your site using framed redirects that hide its true URL?